# Limit maximum connections to NodeJS Server

Tags: node.js

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require("express");
var BinaryServer = require('binaryjs').BinaryServer;
var fs = require('fs');

var addon = require('./build/Release/addon.node');
console.log(addon);

var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;
var WebSocket = require('faye-websocket');
var server = http.createServer(app);

server.maxConnections = 2;//<-----
```

I am trying to limit connections to my http server. To do that I use [maxConnections](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_server_maxconnections_1). Unfortunately this seems not working. Is it because I am testing this in localhost mode?

Comment: It look working well on me!

Comment: @greenlikeorange are you trying in localhost mode? Or in a real server?

Comment: Yes i make in localhost

Comment: Different browsers and same browsers? Sorry about the questions @greenlikeorange

Comment: Well, it work in Cross-browser.